How to run New-LocalUser in Python with subproces
I'm working on a final project for a scripting class at my community college. Recently I used Powershell to add users, give them a password, a description and assign them to a group that was created. Many of these things are assigned to variables within a while loop. One of the key cmdlets was New-LocalUser and the options that followed that as I applied the variables from user input there. We didn't cover subprocesses this semester so I'm at a loss. I've see subprocess.call and using the file path to powershell.exe and I've seen subprocess.run with the comdlet but I'm not having success. The only reason my group is being created is I used an online code converter and it changed it into a try/except setup I'd like to stick as true to my code as I can.
I've tried playing with the subprocess.run and I get the code to run w/o errors but the users aren't created when I go back to Powershell and run the Get-LocalUser cmdlet. I've also had errors related to security with passwords and the echo in terminal but I can get around that with some admin usage.
I'll attach my ps1 code that I'm trying to convert here for some clarity.
echo "Hello, I am C-3PO. I understand you'd like to add some new users to your system today. I'll be happy to assist you."
#This echos out a greeting and let's the user know what we're doing today.
$Count = Read-Host "How many users are we creating today?"
#I'm creating a variable called Count that I will use later to control a loop.
$Count = [int]$Count
#I'm casting the type of Count to be an integer for simplicity.   
$Total = 0
#This is another variable to control my loop, I'll increase it with each loop.
$Group = Read-Host "We want to be sure all of these new users can find each other. 
What would you like to call their group?" 
#As we're putting all these users into a group I asked the user what we should call it.
New-LocalGroup -Name $Group -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
#I've created a group with the name provided by the user, if that name already exists they won't see an error
while ($Total -ne $Count)
#This is the start of my while loop
{
    $FirstName = Read-Host "What is the first name of the user you'd like to create?"
    $MiddleName = Read-Host "What is thier middle name, if they don't have one kindly press enter."
    $LastName = Read-Host "Also, may I know thier last name?"
    #I've taken steps to get the new users full name as it will be eaiser to use in the subsequent sections.
    $Username = ($FirstName.Substring(0,1) + $LastName)
    #I've created a username variable based on the prior inputs
    $FullName = ($FirstName + " " + $MiddleName + " " + $LastName)
    #I've combined the answers above to get their full name
    $Password = Read-Host -AsSecureString "What password would you like to give " $FullName "?"
    #I've assigned user input to the variable Password
    $Description = Read-Host "Would you like to tell me a little about " $FullName "?" " If not simply press enter."
    New-LocalUser -Name $Username -Password $Password -FullName $FullName -Description $Description
    #I've created a new user with the informaiton the current user has provided
    Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $Group -Member $Username
    #I've added the most recent user to the group that was created before the while loop.
    $Total = $Total+1
    #I've moved my Total up by 1 so that this loop won't run forever.
}
echo "`n It's been a pleasure in helping you add these $Count users today.
I do hope you'll inform Master James of my performance."
#I've added a farewell to include my name, I did this in place of naming the group myself.

Here's the, VERY ROUGH, Python code as I have it right now; I know some commented lines will be removed. We haven't covered the try/except stuff and that's from a converter and I refuse to use things I don't understand.
import subprocess
from easygui import passwordbox

print("""Hello, I am C-3PO. I understant you'd like to add some new users to your system today
I'll be happy to assist you with this task.""")

Count = int(input("How many users are we creating today?"))

Total = 0

GroupName = input("""We want to be sure all of the new users can find each other; comradery is so important you know.
Let’s create a group for them. What would you like the group to be called?""")

#try:
subprocess.run(["net", "localgroup", GroupName, "/add"], check=True)
#except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
#    print(f"Error creating local group '{GroupName}': {e}")
total = 0
#count = int(input("How many users would you like to create? "))

while total != Count:
    first_name = input("What is the first name of the user you'd like to create? ")
    middle_name = input("What is their middle name, if they don't have one kindly press enter. ")
    last_name = input("Also, may I know their last name? ")
    username = (first_name[0] + last_name)
    full_name = (first_name + " " + middle_name + " " + last_name)
    password = passwordbox("What password would you like to give " + full_name + "? ")
    description = input("Would you like to tell me a little about " + full_name + "? If not simply press enter. ")
    group = GroupName
    subprocess.run(["net", "localuser", username, "/add"], check=True)
# "-Name $username", "-Password $password", "-FullName $full_name", "-Description $description"
#    subprocess.call("C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe New-LocalUser", shell=True)
    total += 1

print("\nIt's been a pleasure in helping you add these {count} users today.")
print("I do hope you'll inform Master James of my performance.")

I've cleaned this up a bit, now neither the group nor the users are created but have a feeling this is just a permission issue. I am trying to do elevated authority but keep getting win32secuiry issues as I can't import that and it's needed for pyuac to work. Here's a cleaner version
import subprocess
#import pyuac
from easygui import passwordbox
#from win32security import *

#if not pyuac.isUserAdmin():
#    print("Re-launching as Admin!")
#    pyuac.runAsAdmin()
print("""Hello, I am C-3PO. I understant you'd like to add some new users to your system today
I'll be happy to assist you with this task.""")

Count = int(input("How many users are we creating today?"))

Total = 0

GroupName = input("""We want to be sure all of the new users can find each other; comradery is so important you know.
Let’s create a group for them. What would you like the group to be called?""")

subprocess.run(["net", "localgroup", GroupName, "/add"], check=True)
total = 0

while total != Count:
    first_name = input("What is the first name of the user you'd like to create? ")
    middle_name = input("What is their middle name, if they don't have one kindly press enter. ")
    last_name = input("Also, may I know their last name? ")
    username = (first_name[0] + last_name)
    full_name = (first_name + " " + middle_name + " " + last_name)
    password = passwordbox("What password would you like to give " + full_name + "? ")
    description = input("Would you like to tell me a little about " + full_name + "? If not simply press enter. ")
    user=username
    group = GroupName
    subprocess.run(["net", "localuser", user, password, description, "/add"], check=False)
    total += 1

print("\nIt's been a pleasure in helping you add these {count} users today.")
print("I do hope you'll inform Master James of my performance.")

Okay, at this point I've worked out almost all of the issues. I'm just not getting the full name and description to carry over. I know it goes in the same line as the net user /add line and I know I don't have the commands in there yet. I just can't find the right syntax to tell it to add those items; I also don't know if the order matters.
import subprocess, os, sys
from easygui import passwordbox
print("""Hello, I am C-3PO. I understant you'd like to add some new users to your system today
I'll be happy to assist you with this task.""")

Count = int(input("How many users are we creating today?"))

Total = 0

GroupName = input("""We want to be sure all of the new users can find each other; comradery is so important you know.
Let’s create a group for them. What would you like the group to be called?""")
subprocess.run(["net", "localgroup", GroupName, "/add"], check=True)

total = 0

while total != Count:
    first_name = input("What is the first name of the user you'd like to create? ")
    middle_name = input("What is their middle name, if they don't have one kindly press enter. ")
    last_name = input("Also, may I know their last name? ")
    username = (first_name[0:1] + last_name)
    full_name = (first_name + " " + middle_name + " " + last_name)
    password = passwordbox("What password would you like to give " + full_name + "? ")
    description = input("Would you like to tell me a little about " + full_name + "? If not simply press enter. ")
    user=username
    group = GroupName
    subprocess.run(["net", "user", user, password, "/add"], check=True)
    subprocess.run(["net", "localgroup", GroupName, user,"/add"], check=True)
    total += 1

print("\nIt's been a pleasure in helping you add these {count} users today.")
print("I do hope you'll inform Master James of my performance.")

I could really use some help with this last part.

Welcome to SO, James. subprocess.run is used in Python. This question does not show any Python code. If this PowerShell code is run from a PowerShell Console, does it work correctly?

The code here is Powershell and runs in that. I'm looking to convert it to python.  I'm having a hard time with the cmdlets and wanted to use subprocess.run to use them. I can change the Read-Host to inputs and the echos to prints but I'm stuck on the other stuff

I've added where I am with Python as well. Rough doesn't say it as to where I am. There is very much a first draft.

My big problem now is finding the equivalent in python to the New-LocalUser -Name $Username -Password $Password -FullName $FullName -Description $Description and the similar one of adding them to the group.

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61172842/447901

It would, but once I get pyuac installed so I can import it I keep getting module not found issues with win32security. I've tried python -m pip install with pywin32 and win32secuirty but the module error persists. If I try to import win32 security I just get the error sooner. I've cleaned up the code and, If I turn off the second check, it will "run" fine but not create the user. My issue has to be in this line of code

subprocess.run(["net", "localuser", user, password, description, "/add"], check=True)

Now I'm getting errors on the group code as well, I have a hunch it's related to needing elevated privilages. Funny thing is I had it creating the group for the last few days until I deleted some lines I'd commented out but now I can't even get that part to work. I know the rest of it "works" as it was creating the names and such correctly. Biggest downside is that the password seems to be stored as plain text even though passwordbox displays ****** as I type.

I'm using IDLE 3.12.2 and, if i run it as an admin I get through the group creating w/o issue but the user gives me this error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\cislabuser\Desktop\JCraw Local Users.py", line 32, in 
subprocess.run(["net", "localuser", user, password, description, "/add"], check=True)
File "C:\Users\cislabuser\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 571, in run
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['net', 'localuser', '1Skywalker', 'Jedi', "He's a Jedi Knight", '/add']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
